# Check if all elements present in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find whether all elements of the array are found inside an array in a MongoDB database using mongoose.

If my data in MongoDB is -

```
{
  row: "A",
  reserve: [1,2,3]
}
```

and if my query data is -

```
{
  row: "A",
  arr: [1,2] // I want it to return result
}
```

and if my query data is

```
{
  row: "A",
  arr: [1,2,4] // I want it to return null
}
```

I want to update the data but it is updating every time

```
Reserved.updateOne({row: "A", reserve: {$in: arr}, {
  $push: {
    reserve: arr
  }
}, (err, result) => {
  // ...
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: Try this `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      reserve: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$reserve",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "$$this",
              [
                1,
                2
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])`

Comment: I want to use `findOne` because I am using `updateOne` for updating data.

Comment: ***I am using updateOne for updating data*** not clear what you are asking

Comment: I have edited my query,please check.

Comment: Try this `db.collection.updateOne({
  row: "A",
  reserve: {
    $all: arr
  }
})`

Comment: Thnx it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$all` operator ([link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)). Something like:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
        {
          row: "A",
          reserve: { $all: array } 
        }
)
```

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`$all`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) operator to match all the elements from the array.

From the docs

> The [**`$all`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all)  operator selects the documents where the value of a field is
>   an array that contains all the specified elements.

```
db.collection.updateOne({ "row": "A", "reserve": { "$all": array }})
```

or even with find query

```
db.collection.find({ "row": "A", "reserve": { "$all": array }})
```